# What does org.sikuli.api.ScreenRegion error in sikuli means?

Tags: python, sikuli

I am using Python 2.7 and I have installed sikuli_cpython from [here](https://github.com/kevlened/sikuli_cpython).

I have a simple script:

```
from sikuli.sikuli import *

symbol_image ='symbol.jpg'
t = find(symbol_image)
print t
click(t)
```

When I run it, I get the following error message:

```
File "C:\Projects\sikuli1.py", line 112, in <module>
    click(t)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sikuli-0.1-py2.7.egg\sikuli\sikuli.py", line 61, in click
    loc = Pattern(target_string).getLocation()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sikuli-0.1-py2.7.egg\sikuli\sikuli.py", line 139, in getLocation
    t = self.getTarget()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sikuli-0.1-py2.7.egg\sikuli\sikuli.py", line 135, in getTarget
    return self._get_target_from_string(self.target_string)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sikuli-0.1-py2.7.egg\sikuli\sikuli.py", line 148, in _get_target_from_string
    target_file_loc = self._find_local_file(target_string)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sikuli-0.1-py2.7.egg\sikuli\sikuli.py", line 162, in _find_local_file
    poss_relative_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), target_string)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 73, in join
    elif isabs(b):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 57, in isabs
    s = splitdrive(s)[1]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 125, in splitdrive
    if p[1:2] == ':': 
TypeError: 'org.sikuli.api.ScreenRegion' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I know sikuli is used in jython. I have already worked with the sikuli ide and I have installed jython 2.5.3. Although, I experience problems using jython easy_install sikuli.

Answer (score 0):

i have no expertise with sikuli_cpython. but from the point of view of sikuli ide (jython) the object `symbol_image` is not correctly declared. find and click functions require a Pattern object, the way you declared it seems as a string.
try:

```
symbol_image = Pattern('symbol.jpg')
```

but you might need to provide full path to the image directory, and use .png extension.

Answer (score 0):

Above error is coming as Sikuli is trying to locate image file "symbol.jpg" in local folder where your script resides. I think by putting symbol image in same folder as script, this error will disappear.

Sikuli works better with png file formats for images.
Also you can set image bundle path to a folder location where script can find images used in test script.

```
import os
from org.sikuli.script import ImagePath
img_path = os.path.join(<Project-directory>, <images_folder>)
ImagePath.setBundlePath(img_path)
```